# Java Rendering 2D or 3D, what & how?

Tags: java, image, 2d, render, curve

I feel more comfortable when I have some task, dealing with Swing Rather than other topics.
Thus, When I read one of this case I'm a bit confused. 
Preview: [Click Here.](http://img69.imageshack.us/img69/8840/java2d.jpg)

I recall this is about the java 2d topics, in which the shape (oval, line, etc) lessons are covered.
I'm thinking there must be a library for achieving the main result.

1. But how about the coordinate for making a curve with the coordinate,
   what's that different layer? -pic 1 on upper box
2. What are the topics needed to render this image? -pic 1 & 2 both
   boxes
3. Is there any thread discussing about this matter, if so, which one?

Comment: 117x150px is not big enough for me to see what you are talking about. (A picture paints a thousand words, unless it is whispering.)

Comment: What have you tried so far? What experience do you have with 2d/3d rendering? Are you willing to try something like lwjgl?

Comment: See [Trail: 2D Graphics](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/2d/) in Oracle's Java Tutorials.

Comment: sorry-sorry... i've done updating the reuploaded image.... @AndrewThompson, please check it again.